# I am not able to automate the shell script to automate the go compilation. Im using ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell

I want to automate the compilation of GO lang. I have shell script

```
for i in *.go
do
    echo "go build -o ${i%.*} $i"
  
done
```

but this is just printing out the output but not executing.

Output:
./c.sh

```
go build -o binarytrees binarytrees.go     
 go build -o fannkuch fannkuch.go  
go build -o fasta.go-2 fasta.go-2.go
```

but it does not actually execute these commands.

Comment: That's not how Go works. Just use `go build . -o <output>` If you have multiple .go files in the same directory that are meant to be compiled separately, then you're doing it "wrong". Move them each to their own directory.

Comment: Use `make`, https://tutorialedge.net/golang/makefiles-for-go-developers/

Comment: Yeah I collected independent go scripts that would run like that and wanted an automated compilation. Thanks so much.

Comment: `echo` is **printing** the arguments it gets. That's the purpose of this command. Why do you think that the arguments would be executed? For instance, `echo hello world` writes _hello world_ to stdout. It does **not** run a programm named `hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo commands doesn't execute the statements rather they just print the expression written under `""`.
To complete the build you would do something like this

```
for i in *.go
  do
    echo "go build -o ${i%.*} $i"
    go build -o ${i%.*} $i
  done
```

Or you can even pipe your command into shell by `echo "go build x y" | bash -`